# BSOD error: Page Fault in Non-Paged Area while using signals with FIFOS (IPC) in WSL Ubuntu (Windows 10)

Tags: linux, ipc

I'm trying to write a basic IPC program which creates two processes using fork() and execv() system calls, and using names pipes(FIFOs) for communication(in order to retrieve the pid of new process). Whenever I run them in parallel, I get a BSOD error on Windows 10(WSL Ubuntu). This is a very generic problem, I have tried rectifying it by running them in new directories, and sometimes surprisingly it works. This happens very often with programs involving fifos( especially when I use an exec system call) and signals, however for other programs it works fine. I don't really know the main cause of the problem, but it's really annoying when the system goes off each time I'm running a program. I wished to find out what might be a possible cause for this problem. I've also checked available disk space and it seems to be fine.
( Doesn't occur in any other scenario apart from the aforementioned ones). Following is an example code:

```
//main 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<pthread.h>
using namespace std;

int pid;
pthread_t thread;

void* func(void* param){
    cout<<"Thread of parent running"<<endl;
    for(int times=0;times<3;++times){
        sleep(4);
    }
    kill(pid,SIGUSR2);
    return NULL;
}


int main(){
    pid_t c=fork();
    if(c > 0){
        mkfifo("child",0666);
        int fd=open("child",O_RDONLY);
        read(fd,&pid,1024);
        close(fd);

        sleep(2);

        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,func,NULL);
        pthread_join(thread,NULL);
    }
    else{
        char* argv[]={NULL};
        execv("./P2",argv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
//new process
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<pthread.h>
using namespace std;

pthread_t thread;
pid_t currPid;

void handler(int signm){
    cout<<"Thread of child signalled by parent"<<endl;
    cout<<"Child thread killed"<<endl;
    pthread_kill(thread,SIGKILL);
}

void* fun(void* param){
    cout<<"Thread of child running"<<endl;
    sleep(20);
    
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGUSR2,handler);

    mkfifo("child",0666);
    int fd=open("child",O_WRONLY);
    if(fd < 0){
        perror("Issue ocurred\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    currPid=getpid();
    write(fd,&currPid,1024);
    close(fd);

    sleep(1);

    pthread_create(&thread,NULL,fun,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread,NULL);

    return 0;

}
```